# Bentley-Ottmann Algorithm Implementation

Tags: c#, java, computational-geometry, line-intersection, line-segment

Is there any existing Bentley-Ottmann Algorithm Implementation/library in C# or Java?

Comment: take a look at here ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490331/implementing-the-bentley-ottmann-algorithm

Comment: Did you ever get this fully working? The Java implementation link is dead now.

Comment: What output are you expecting from the implementation?

Comment: Not C# or Java, but heres a single-file implementation you could port http://stackoverflow.com/a/33199826/432509

Comment: Has anyone sighted a public C# implementation yet? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://web.archive.org/web/20040329071207/http://www.solyanik.com/sergey/sweep11/) is a Java implementation of the Bentley-Ottman algorithm

Comment: Java link is still available here: http://web.archive.org/web/20040329071207/http://www.solyanik.com/sergey/sweep11/

Answer (score 4):

Here is at least a C++ implementation (including description):
http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0108/algorithm_0108.htm

Comment: While technically this is a bentley-ottmann implementation, its only returning true/false. Not finding all intersection points.

Answer (score 0):

The implmentation at softsurfer.com is the Shamos-Hoey algorithm to decide if there is at least one intersection. And, if one is found, it stops. The code at the reference is for testing if a polygon is simple.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30795816)

Comment: I was the author of that code, and that is my website. The website has been converted to a book, and this code is no longer available online, As for the code you are discussing, it was for the Shamos-Hoey algorithm which historically preceded the Bentley-Ottman. Shamos-Hoey was for testing if a polygon is simple, so it only returns true or false. It stops as soon as it finds one intersection.